# Help in Frequency Conversion in ArduinoRP2040

Tags: frequency, arduino-nano-rp2040

Having a bit of a problem with the Arduino Nano RP2040. I'm trying to use the onboard microphone to read the frequency of a sound and then use that variable for calculations. However, while I can get the mic to respond to audio stimulus, I'm not sure what the values being recorded actually are. I want to be able to play for example a note at 80 Hz. I need to be able to identify a note.

Comment: Your last sentence does not make sense to me. Are you trying to _play_ a note, or to _identify_ a note?

Comment: install Audacity on your computer  record a sound and examine the recorded data ... https://www.audacityteam.org/